# ¿Porque las imagenes embebidas que se envian por correo se ven como si fueran archivos descargables?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estoy usando la librería PHPMailer para enviar correos.
Para hacerlo ocupo esta plantilla html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Activa tu cuenta</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-8 p-5 mx-auto bg-white rounded content">
         <h1 class="text-center display-1">Bienvenido!</h1>
    <div class="mt-5">
     <p>var:nombre, Estamos emocionados de que comiences. Primero debes confirmar tu cuenta. Simplemente presione el botón de abajo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center mt-5">
     <a href="var:url">
      <img src="var:imagen" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="var:cuenta" style="max-width: 200px;"><br>
      <span class="btn btn-primary col-lg-6 rounded">Confirmar Cuenta</span>
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-5">
     <p>Si eso no funciona, copie y pegue el siguiente enlace en su navegador:</p>
     <a href="var:url">var:url</a>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-5">
     <p>Si tiene alguna pregunta, solo responda a este correo electrónico, siempre nos complace ayudarlo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-5">
     <blockquote class="blockquote text-right">
       <p class="mb-0">HomeWorkLine</p>
       <footer class="blockquote-footer">El equipo de HomeWorkLine</footer>
     </blockquote>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Proceso para cargar una plantilla html y enviar correo**

1. *Leo la plantilla.*
2. *Cargo los estilos.*
   Para cargar los archivos css no tengo ningun problema ya que lo hago a través de la librería "CssInliner::fromHtml()" el cual me ayuda a convertir las clases de mi plantilla como estilo en linea.
3. *Inserto mis variables dentro de la plantilla.*
   Para hacer esto, dentro de mi plantilla html ocupo la palabra "var:"+"nombre de variable".
   (En esta plantilla ocupo 4 variables las cuales son var:nombre, var:cuenta, var:imagen, var:url) y solo lo reemplazo por el contenido que quiero.
4. *Cargo las imágenes.*
   Con la expresión regular '/\"|\'[^>]*[^>]+/' obtengo la ruta de las imágenes que contenga mi plantilla. (Si la ruta es relativa la proceso para obtener la ruta absoluta de la imagen).
   Reemplazo lo que contenga el "src" por "cid:image".
   Después la inserto al correo con la funcion "AddEmbeddedImage()" de PHPMailer.
   AddEmbeddedImage($pathIMG, 'image', 'image.png');

Después de todo eso si todo esta bien procedo a *enviar el correo*.

Asi llega el correo a su destinatario:
[image: Así se ve el correo cuando llega.]

Pero la imagen me llega como si fuese un archivo asi:
[image: Me muestra la imagen como si fuera un archivo]

**¿Es normal que pase esto?**

Al igual trate de enviar la imagen en base64 pero sigo obteniendo los mismos resultados en donde la imagen me la muestra como fuese un archivo.

Esta es mi clase que envía donde instancio PHPMailer:

> class email

```
if(!@include_once('../../main.php'));

// PHPMailer: Enviar correos
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// CssInliner: Style dentro de las etiquetas html
use Pelago\Emogrifier\CssInliner;

class email
{
    // Atributos
    private $host = SMTP_HOST;
    private $user = SMTP_USER;
    private $password = SMTP_PASS;
    private $port = SMTP_PORT;
    private $subname = PROJECT_TITLE;

    private $email;

    public $html;
    private $pathHTML;

    // Constructor
    function __construct()
    {
        $this -> email = new PHPMailer(true);
        $this -> email -> isSMTP();
        $this -> email -> SMTPAuth = true;
        $this -> email -> SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $this -> email -> Host = $this -> host;
        $this -> email -> Port = $this -> port;
        $this -> email -> Username = $this -> user;
        $this -> email -> Password = $this -> password;
        $this -> email -> CharSet = 'UTF-8';

        $this -> email -> setFrom($this -> user, $this -> subname);
        $this -> email -> AddReplyTo($this -> user, $this -> subname);

        $this -> email -> isHTML();

        $this -> email -> ContentType = 'text/html';
    }


    public function setAddress($address, $user = '')
    {
        $this -> email -> addAddress($address, $user);
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this -> email -> Subject = $title;
        $this -> email -> AltBody = $title;
    }

    public function setHTML($path)
    {
        if(!is_readable($path))
        {
            setError(get_class(), 'Verifica que el archivo "' . $path . '" exista.');
            return false;
        }

        $this -> pathHTML = $path;
        $this -> html = file_get_contents($path);

        if(!self :: importStyles())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function importStyles()
    {
        // Obtiene la ruta de los archivos css de la plantilla html
        Preg_match_all('/<link.*rel=[\"|\']stylesheet[\"|\'].*href=[\"|\']([^\"|\']*)[^>]*[^>]+/', $this -> html, $css);

        // Elimina la etiqueta <link> que importa los css
        $this -> html = preg_replace('/(<link.*)stylesheet.*(>)/', '', $this -> html);

        // Escribe los archivos css como estilos de linea
        foreach ($css[1] as $key => $pathCSS) {
            $pathCSS = (strpos($pathCSS, 'http://') === false) ? substr($this -> pathHTML, 0, strrpos($this -> pathHTML, '/') + 1) . $pathCSS : $pathCSS;
            $file = @file_get_contents($pathCSS);
            if($file === false)
            {
                setError(get_class(), 'Verifica que el archivo "' . $pathCSS . '" exista.');
                return false;
            }
            $this -> html = CssInliner::fromHtml($this -> html)->inlineCss($file)->render();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private function importImages()
    {
        // Obtiene la ruta de las imagenes de la plantilla html
        Preg_match_all('/<img.*src=[\"|\']([^\"|\']*)[^>]*[^>]+/', $this -> html, $img);

        foreach ($img[1] as $key => $pathIMG) {
            $this -> html = str_replace($pathIMG, 'cid:image', $this -> html);
            $pathIMG = (strpos($pathIMG, ROOT_PATH) === false) ? substr($this -> pathHTML, 0, strrpos($this -> pathHTML, '/') + 1) . $pathIMG : $pathIMG;
            try
            {
                $file = new \SplFileInfo($pathIMG);
                $ext = $file -> getExtension();
                $this -> email -> AddEmbeddedImage($pathIMG, 'image', 'image.' . $ext);
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                setError(get_class(), 'No se pudo añadir la imagen "' . $pathIMG . '" al contenido html.');
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function setVar($var, $value)
    {
        $match = stripos($this -> html, 'var:' . $var);
        if($match === false)
        {
            setError(get_class(), 'La variable "' . $var . '" no fue encontrada.');
            return false;
        }
        $this -> html = str_replace( 'var:' . $var, $value, $this -> html);
        return true;
    }

    public function send()
    {
        if(!self :: importImages())
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            $this -> email -> msgHTML($this -> html);
            return $this -> email -> send();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getError()
    {
        return $this -> email -> ErrorInfo;
    }
}
```

> Registro de usuarios

```
if(!@include_once('../../../php/main.php'));

$nombre = getPost('nombre', 's', true);
$apellido = getPost('apellido', 's', true);
$correo = getPost('correo', 's', true);
$password = getPost('password', 's', true);
$tipo_cuenta = getPost('tipo_cuenta', 'i', true);

if($tipo_cuenta != 2 && $tipo_cuenta != 3)
{
    show_status(5, 'El tipo de registro es invalido.');
}

$nombre_cuenta;
$imagen_cuenta;
switch ($tipo_cuenta)
{
    case 2:
        $nombre_cuenta = 'Maestro';
        $imagen_cuenta = ROOT_PATH . 'lib/images/web/maestro-512x512.png';
        break;
    case 3:
        $nombre_cuenta = 'Alumno';
        $imagen_cuenta = ROOT_PATH . 'lib/images/web/alumno-512x512.png';
        break;
}

$usuario = new usuarios\usuarios();

if($usuario -> existCorreo($correo))
{
    show_status(5, 'Este correo ya fue registrado. Registrate con otro correo.');
}

$usuario -> nombre      = $nombre;
$usuario -> apellido    = $apellido;
$usuario -> correo      = $correo;
$usuario -> password    = $password;
$usuario -> tipo_cuenta = $tipo_cuenta;

if(!$usuario -> registrar())
{
    show_status(4, 'Ocurrio un error al tratar de registrate. Intentalo nuevamente.');
}
else
{
    if(!$usuario -> setTypeAccount($tipo_cuenta, 1))
    {
        show_status(4, 'Ocurrio un error al tratar de crear tu cuenta. Intentalo nuevamente.');
    }
    else
    {
        $email = new email\email();

        $email -> setAddress($correo);
        $email -> setTitle('Activa tu cuenta');

        $email -> setHTML(ROOT_PATH . 'lib/templates/html/email/usuarios/registro.html');

        $email -> setVar('nombre', $nombre);
        $email -> setVar('imagen', $imagen_cuenta);
        $email -> setVar('cuenta', $nombre_cuenta);

        $action =
        [
            'enty' => 'user',
            'action' => 'activate'
        ];
        $params =
        [
            'id' => $usuario -> id,
            'tipo_cuenta' => $usuario -> tipo_cuenta
        ];

        $url = ROOT_HOST . arrayEncodeURL($action, $params);
        $email -> setVar('url', $url);

        if(!$email -> send())
        {
            show_status(4, 'Ocurrio un error al enviar el correo. Intentalo mas tarde.');
        }
        else
        {
            show_status(2, 'Activa tu cuenta haciendo click en el correo enviado.');
        }
    }
}
```

**Nota:** Las imagenes las importo al llamar al metodo send() ya que de esta manera me aseguro de que todas las variables de mi plantilla ya fuerón reemplazadas por su reespectivo contenido.

Answer (score 0):

Eso es porque el correo te detecta que hay un archivo de por medio, mientras en el cuerpo del mensaje se vea lo que necesitas no veo el porque eliminar ese tipo de foto...

Lo otro que podes hacer es poner la imagen en una etiqueta `<img src='' alt=''></img>`

Answer (score 0):

También me sucede lo mismo y no he podido dar con el problema. Otros correos llegan con HTML e imágenes embebidas y no se muestran como un descargable. Si encuentras la solución por favor me dices. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Diego, bienvenido, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, 

si tienes alguna duda, crea tu propia pregunta, para recibir ayuda, antes 

mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.